# PHP : Use echo after readfile

Tags: php, echo, readfile

I'm developing a web application.

A user can download a specific zip file using readfile() if the zip has been correctly generated.

But since I've integrated the readfile() line, I can't echo anything before or after this line. Here is the code sample causing problem :

```
 if($zip->status == 0){

    $zip->close();

    $file_url = './zip/'.$userDir.'.zip';
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\"");
    readfile($file_url);

    echo'
    <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
    Success
    </div>';

  }
```

Everything in the condition is called except for the echo lines at the end. When I remove the readfile($file_url) line, the echo is called.

I also tried to move the echo lines before the line

```
$file_url = './zip/'.$userDir.'.zip';
```

And it doesn't work either. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Please, make your code easier to maintain for yourself by closing the PHP tags when outputting HTML. If you aren't aware of the [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Comment: Why is that easier to maintain? He is not working in a HTML file...

Comment: Because it is neater as it isn't wrapped in an echo.

Comment: Because it allows HTML to exist as HTML, not a PHP string, with escaping, an eye on which quotes to use, concatenation etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you echo after "sending the file" to the user you are going to corrupt the file.

You have to think as the php code as a download link, the user clicks on it and get a file. Also sending an echo is not going to the user screen since you have this headers

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. I removed both of those headers and moved the echo line before the $file_url variable. The echo line is still not being called.

Comment: you can not echo to the user while sending data binary etc.. your echo will be added to the download file and it may be corrupted when finish download.

Comment: just a note, the echo line is being called, but sent as part of the file, that's why you don't see it on the browser.

Comment: So there is basically no way to echo something and use readfile() at the same time ?

Comment: No, you are reading a file and sending it to the browser for download, all you sent will be part of that file. You can accomplish what you want with an ajax, and sending the user to a _blank page for the download, and then make the appropriate changes on the current DOM object.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case, a submitted form is generating a pdf file but since automatic download is initiated with readfile() on the action page, HTML of the latter wouldn't load, the browser keeps the form page open - that's where I added an overlay div which becomes visible only after clicking submit, blocking all content except a simple button which takes to the same action page but with the help of GET information, readfile() code isn't running again. Sure a button has to be clicked but it can be a good thing, some sort of download acknowledgement.

It feels, however, a bit odd, loading the same page twice.